# window sql function on stream api java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, java-stream

I have the following table. I need not to take duplicates for the templateId field if the following condition is triggered: if the source fields are different, then take the templateId field whose runCount is the largest.

| id | templateId | runCount | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | SBS |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | LBS |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | SBS |
| 4 | 3 | 10 | SBS |

That is, the table should look like this

| id | templateId | runCount | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | LBS |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | SBS |
| 3 | 3 | 10 | SBS |

I wrote the following query and it returns what I need, but I can’t insert a check into it for the `source` field

```
List<Entity> autoGens = repository
           .findAllByRemoved(false);

List<Entity> autoGensResult= autoGens.stream().
        collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Entity::getTemplateId,
                maxBy(comparing(Entity::getRunCount))),
                m -> m.values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(toList())));
```

Help me check in this request that the `source` fields are different

Comment: maybe something like this `List<Entity> autoGensResult= autoGens.stream().filter(condition)....collect(toList())));` can help you.

Comment: What do you want to do when the `source` field is the same? The current sample shared by you doesn't cover this use case either. Also, when you say the source fields are different, you are only bothered about them *if* the `templateId` is same?